# Using Switch Statement to Handle Button Clicks

Tags: android, button, listener

I'm trying to wrap my head around Views, Listeners etc.  I have an Activity with 2 Buttons: buttonplay and buttonstop.  My problem is I can't wrap my head around the Views and Listeners completely enough to generate a working switch statement.

For example, I would LIKE to create a SINGLE Listener and somehow use it to determine which button is clicked.  Then somehow use the ID of the button clicked in my switch statement,  But everything I find online seems to use SEPARATE listeners for every button and then somehow use the View as the argument to the Switch statement.

I realize the code below is not correct, but am looking for what changes I would need to accomplish the above.

I want to control the MediaPlayer depending on which button is clicked.  I have:

```
   Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);       
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()         
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on click
          switch(v.getId()) {
          case R.id.buttonplay:
          //Play voicefile
          MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).start();
          break;
          case R.id.buttonstop:
          //Stop MediaPlayer
              MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).stop();
          break;
         }
   }
    });
```

Ultimately I would like the most straighforward way to switch on whatever button is clicked. I believe a big part of my confusion stems from the way onClickListeners and Views are used in this context.

Answer (score 43):

One way of achieving this is to make your class implement OnClickListener and then add it to your buttons like this:

Example:

```
//make your class implement OnClickListener
public class MyClass implements OnClickListener{

        ...

        //Create your buttons and set their onClickListener to "this"
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);   
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);   
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        ...

        //implement the onClick method here
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on click
          switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonplay:
              //Play voicefile
              MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).start();
              break;
            case R.id.buttonstop:
              //Stop MediaPlayer
              MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).stop();
              break;
          }
       }
}
```

For more information see [Android Developers > Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

Comment: This *May* have been what I was looking for..one question though: my class is a third Activity in my APK so I have already defined it to be: public class Activity3 extends Activity since it is a SEPARATE activity..can I use implements in this Activity class?

Comment: @user615525 yes, you should be able to declare it as: `public class Activity3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener`

Answer (score 6):

Just change the class (I suppose it's the main Activity) to implement View.OnClickListener and on the onClick method put the general onClick actions you want to put:

```
public class MediaPlayer extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);       
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    //{YOUR APP}
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonplay:
        //Play voicefile
        MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).start();
        break;
    case R.id.buttonstop:
        //Stop MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).stop();
        break;
    }

}}
```

I took it from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm-hNlTD1H0 . It's good for starters.

Answer (score 5):

Hi its quite simple to make switch between buttons using switch case:-

```
 package com.example.browsebutton;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button b1,b2;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

                b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                b1.setOnClickListener(this);
                b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            }



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 int id=v.getId();
                 switch(id) {
                    case R.id.button1:
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "btn1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Your Operation

                  break;

                    case R.id.button2:
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "btn2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                          //Your Operation
                          break;
            }

        }}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that the simplest way to do this is to set onClick for each button in the xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/vrHelp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_help"
android:onClick="helpB" />
```

and then you can do a switch case like this

```
  public void helpB(View v) {
    Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
    switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
      case R.id.vrHelp:
        dosomething...
        break;

      case R.id.coHelp:
        dosomething...
        break;

      case R.id.ksHelp:
        dosomething...
        break;

      case R.id.uHelp:
        dosomething...
        break;

      case R.id.pHelp:
        dosomething...
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

One mistake what i did was not including "implements OnClickListener" in the main class declaration. This is a sample code to clearly illustrate the use of switch case during on click. The code changes background colour as per the button pressed. 
Hope this helps.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{


TextView displayText;
Button cred, cblack, cgreen, cyellow, cwhite;
LinearLayout buttonLayout;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cred = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bred);
    cblack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bblack);
    cgreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgreen);
    cyellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.byellow);
    cwhite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bwhite);
    displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
    buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llbuttons);

    cred.setOnClickListener(this);
    cblack.setOnClickListener(this);
    cgreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    cyellow.setOnClickListener(this);
    cwhite.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onClick(View V){
    int id=V.getId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.bred:
        displayText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        vanishLayout();
        break;
    case R.id.bblack:
        displayText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        vanishLayout();
        break;
    case R.id.byellow:
        displayText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
        vanishLayout();
        break;
    case R.id.bgreen:
        displayText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
        vanishLayout();
        break;
    case R.id.bwhite:
        displayText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        vanishLayout();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) with switch-case to handle this kind of cases:

```
    @OnClick({R.id.button_bireysel, R.id.button_kurumsal})
        public void onViewClicked(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {


                case R.id.button_bireysel:
 //Do something

                    break;
                case R.id.button_kurumsal:

     //Do something

                    break;

            }
        }
```

But the thing is there is no default case and switch statement falls through

Answer (score 0):

```
    XML CODE FOR TWO BUTTONS  
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:onClick="process"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SHOW"
            android:onClick="process"/> 

  Java Code
 <pre> public void process(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_save:
                  //add your own code
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_show:
                   //add your own code
                    break;
            }</pre>
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? A little explanation really improves your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the things you missed out was that you failed to declare the stop button b2, you only declared and initialized b1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).