# OnTouchListener for the entire screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, motion-detection

I would like to have a OnTouchListener for the entire screen. I've tried attaching all views to an onTouchListener but generates bad touchEvents. I know this can be achived by overriding methods, what i am looking for is a listener solution. Thanks!

Can this be done using a gesture listener?

Comment: The link below explains how to do it using an image: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763 Someone at SO had a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648985/ontouchlistener-for-entire-screen As far as a gesture listener implementation I have no idea.

Comment: is it possible to make a transparent overlaying view over all views then just listen to the overlaying view? if i click over this overlaying view will the clicks go through to the below views like buttons ?

Comment: I'm not sure Mike. I haven't tried myself. I just tried to cull together some approaches I found while searching for an answer to your question. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a onSwipeListener class with methods that listen to the swipe action. You can then set view.OnTouchListener for the layout of the activity(LinearLayout/RelativeLayout) and then override the various methods of the onSwipeListener and insert the various tasks.

Below is the onSwipeListener class that you can create.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

After creating this class, you can call it as follows:

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(context) {
public void onSwipeRight() {
   //do something
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
   //do something
}

}
```

Hope this helps!