# How can I set attribute onClick to a ScrollView?

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview

I have the following layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answerMainFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:onClick="toQuestion" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/question_img_cd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        style="@style/Question" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Sometimes the `ScrollView` is too small and won't fill the whole screen but still I want to call the method `toQuestion()` clicking anywhere on the screen.

I've tried setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the `LinearLayout` and `android:onClick="toQuestion"` to the `ScrollView` but same result.

Comment: So your actual question is how to always have the entire screen clickable? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648985/ontouchlistener-for-entire-screen) might help..

Comment: I think there may be two questions, how to get the scroll view to fill the screen and how to call that method when it is clicked

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could try to let the `LinearLayout` implement the `onClick` attribute and then set:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to the `ScrollView`.

Comment: That's exactly it @Luksprog. Thanks.

Comment: Read more about this trick here: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and simply got rid of the scrollview itself. Instead, I directly inserted the TextView itself, with the constraints previously put on the ScrollView. The whole purpose of my ScrollView was to scroll in the TextView, not among several items, so it seemed a more elegant way to do.

Add a (vertical) scrollbar to my textview in activity.hmtl :

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
    (...) 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    />
```

Add this to the onCreate method:

```
    oTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    oTV.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

No need to write the scrolling response. I like that.

I found the solution here (thx Juned Mughal) :

http://www.android-examples.com/make-textview-scrollable-in-android-programmatically/

Answer (score -2):

To make the scroll view fill the screen change:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >
```

to

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@android:color/white" >
```

and for the click put this in your onCreate method:

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView))
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        toQuestion();
                    }
                });
```