# findViewById not working when finding layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to make the whole screen clickable so I'm trying to set an id for a layout and find it in java class. When I do this, it says incompatiable types (layout vs a view). I understand they are different types but upon googling this, several posts have suggested selecting the layout in an activity in this manner. They can make a call such as this -

```
RelativeLayout theLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Layout)
```

and they don't seem to be getting this error.

Another stackoverflow post with this - [onTouchListener for entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648985/ontouchlistener-for-entire-screen)

My code referencing this is below -

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/thelayout" >
    <TextView android:text="This will change with speech" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in activity -

```
RelativeLayout theLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.thelayout);
```

Am I missing somethinng?

Comment: I'd say this is more of a Java problem than an Android problem.

Comment: You should cast the findViewById result to RelativeLayout like this:


`RelativeLayout theLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.thelayout);`

Comment: Derp. Dumb move on my part. Thanks that solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
RelativeLayout theLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.thelayout)
```

Try this in your Activity,

```
RelativeLayout theLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.thelayout)
```

Comment: Well, you said that in your Activity you are using `RelativeLayout theLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.thelayout);`. You need to cast it.

Comment: Sorry I just now realized that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setContentView(int layoutResID)` with the layout id, inflate the layout get the view reference and then use the `setContentView(View view)`.

```
View layout = View.inflate(context, R.layout.theLayout, null)
setContentView(layout)
```

You don't need to cast the layout to RelativeLayout, as you can add the click/touch listener to a View class.