# Android: two action on onLongClickListener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

is it possible to perform two actions on onlongclickListener..
below is sample code

```
public class traction implements OnLongClickListener {


    private Activity activity;
    static int i = 0;
    public traction(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    public void onLongClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(activity, login.class);
        activity.startActivity(i);  

    }

    }}
```

here when i press fst time the activity fires, if i do three long presses another acitivity should fire...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag or dynamic flag for that button and use switch statement.

you can find an many [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987670/using-switch-statement-to-handle-button-clicks)

Comment: hi ..i want the same button to perform two actions ..1 click should fire a activity and 3 clciks should fire another acitivity....

Comment: in that case u need to implement your custom Gestures and here an example http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/

Comment: or u can Disabling the button and is not enough, you should also make the button unclickable with setClickable(false).

setEnabled() will only change the appearance of the button, which will continue to receive click events.