# two action in one onlongclick listener android button

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener

I'm very new to android development and I just started to study. So sorry for this simple question.

When I long press button it will pass string successfully but when I release button click it does not pass second string... please let me know where is the problem.

Comment: Exactly what you want to do?

Comment: May be you are returning false in the onlongClick.. return true

Comment: Please paste you code so users can understand where you did the mistake and visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987670/using-switch-statement-to-handle-button-clicks for more information

Answer (score 0):

Long press only fires once use onTouchListener if you want two events to be fired one at ACTION_DOWN and other at ACTION_UP.

EDIT: Use this only if you want two events to be fired one when the user touch the view and other when user lifts the finger from the view.The code can be like this...

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new onTouchListener)
{
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("DOWN","DOWN");
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("MOVE","MOVE");
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
        }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help.sir can u give me proper java activity code because i do not know about ACTION_DOWN ACTION_UP function.

Answer (score 0):

Hii you can use what @pervez other wise you can use `ToggleButton` for example you can use like this.

```
    ToggleButton myButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.myToggle);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    if(myButton.isChecked()){
    doYourMethod1();
    }else{
    doYourMethod2();
}
    });
```

Comment: sir my quesion is when i pressed (hold) on long click listener it will pass on string/text (start) and when i release that button then it will pass another string(stop )