# Android: Logcat shows error on (.setOnClickListener)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, logcat, android-logcat

when i run this code, its not working and the catlog sends me to that line:
"add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {"

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter =0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Badd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bsub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVmain);



        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your Total is: " + counter);
            }
        });
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pluseonecalculator.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

this is the logcat:

> 03-27 23:14:27.150: I/Process(408): Sending signal. PID: 408 SIG: 9
>       03-27 23:27:01.070: D/AndroidRuntime(420): Shutting down VM
>       03-27 23:27:01.070: W/dalvikvm(420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.pluseonecalculator/com.example.pluseonecalculator.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at com.example.pluseonecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>       03-27 23:27:01.090: E/AndroidRuntime(420):    ... 11 more

Comment: What is the error in your logcat output?

Comment: also post activity_main.xml please

Comment: Check out line 34 in MainActivity, "add" could be null. Make sure you've referenced it well from your layout

Comment: @Onik if you want to improve the formatting, please do so without stripping potentially relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Button was pointing to `null` when you tried setting listener here:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

make sure that there exists a Button with the id `Badd` in your activity_main.xml, otherwise findViewById will return `null`:

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Badd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the xml code for your button in activity_main. In order to instantiate the button from the java code using its id you must add this to your activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Badd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any Buttons inside of `activity_main.xml`. If you use `findViewById` then you must have `<Button>` (or whatever you're trying to find) elements as children of your main layout (in this case `FrameLayout`).

ie

```
<FrameLayout
    android:stuff = "stuffystuff"
    ... />
    <Button
        android:id = "ThisIsTheIdThatWillBeFound    // by findViewById(R.id.ThisIsTheIdThatWillBeFound)
        .../>
<FrameLayout>
```

What's currently happening is that there is no `R.id.Badd` because android cannot find anything with `android:id = "@+id/Badd"` to generate it from. Thus, `NullPointerException`.

In your case, add Buttons with the id's `Badd` and `Bsub` to your layout and you shouldn't have any problems. Your buttons will have to have other attributes as well. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

In addition, if you are planning on implementing your second button in a similar way I would consider using your main class as an `OnClickListener` for both buttons (instead of creating two) and when the `OnClick` method is passed a view use its id to control program flow via `switch (view.getId())`. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987721/3454144).