# Switch statement doesn't work in Android studio with Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm beginner in Android and java programming, so i can't understand why my switch statement doesn't work with button elements.

```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button button1;
  Button button2;
  Button button3;
  TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
```

here my problem

```
          public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.button1:
                  textView.setText("Button1 was pressed");
                     break;
              case R.id.button2:
                  textView.setText("Button2 was pressed");
                     break;
             case R.id.button3:
                  textView.setText("Button3 was pressed");
                     break;
                  }
               }
             };



       }
      }
```

I'll be very gratefu if someone help me.

P.S.
I'm beginner in programming

Comment: post if any error?

Comment: No, app is working but textView doesn't change text when i click on them

Comment: Please step through the code with a debugger to find the place were something unexptected happens.

Comment: see the logcat when button press

Comment: A debugger will tell you more than we can.

Comment: button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("Butto1 was pressed");
            }
        });

Comment: when i do that way my text View change text

Comment: implement OnClickListener
Refer this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987670/using-switch-statement-to-handle-button-clicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not write `setOnClickListner` on `Button` and make sure your `Activity` `implements View.OnClickListener` see my code below.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Use this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview) ;

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                textView.setText("Button1 was pressed");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                textView.setText("Button2 was pressed");
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                textView.setText("Button3 was pressed");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @User_art glad to help you.